# File Attachment not going in mail in php

Tags: php, html

I am making a form in html in which there is an upload button and some details of the user.I want to send all the details of the form along with file uploaded from the user.But it is not working.I am posting both the code of my html code and Php code also. Tell me where I am missing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<body>


    <div class="element">
       <a href="index.php"><img src="logo.gif"></a>
           <br><br>
    <div class="new"></div>
    <center><h2>Submit Your Information  below</h2></center>

    <form name="registration" method="post" action="fromaction.php" enctype="mutipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"> 
        <!-- <span class="erorr"> --->
        <div class="image"></div>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input id="box1" placeholder="Type here" type="text" name="Name:" required>
        <br><br>

    <label>Email:</label><input id="box2" placeholder="Type here" type="email" name="Email:" required >
        <br>
        <br>

    <label>Time period in which you will join</label>
            <select id ="myList" name="Time Required by user to Join the company" >
                <option value="Immediate" required>Immediate</option>
                <option value="Less than one month">Less than one month</option>
                <option value="1 month">1 month</option>
                <option value="2 months">2 months</option> 
            </select>

        <br><br>

    <label>Linkedin Link:</label>
        <input type="text" id="box3" name="Linkedin ID" placeholder="https://www" required >
         <br><br>

        <label for="workexcel">What job responsibilities and duties do you excel at?</label>

        <textarea name="At which The User is Excel in:" placeholder="Type Here.." id="add" rows="2" cols="2"  maxlength="300" required></textarea>

        <br><br>  

        <label>Tell me about a challenge or conflict you've faced at work, and how you dealt with it.</label>

            <textarea name="How user dealt with challenge or conflict" placeholder="Type Here.." rows="2" cols="2" maxlength="300"  required ></textarea>        
        <br><br>


            <label for"twork">What is your greatest professional achievement?</label>

                <textarea name="User Professional achievement:" placeholder="Type here.." id="twork" rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="300" required></textarea>
                <br>

                    <br><br>

        <label for="det">Tell us something about Yourself</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <textarea name= "Details About the user" placeholder="Type here.." id="det" rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="300" required ></textarea>

            <br><br>

        <label for="resume">Attach Your Resume here </label>

        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
        <br><br>


        <input type="checkbox"  value="Area" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;I understand that I am applying for the job which is of my Area of field.
        <br>
        <h1><input id="submit" type="Submit" value="Submit"></h1>


        <!-- </span> -->
    </form>     


    </div>
    </body>
    </head>
    </html>
```

**PHP code here**

```
    <?php

    $c_name=$_POST['Name:']; // Contain Candidate name 
    $c_email=$_POST['Email:']; // Contain email 
    $c_time=$_POST['Time Required by user to Join the company']; 
    $c_linkedin=$_POST['Linkedin ID'];
    $c_Excel=$_POST['At which The User is Excel in:'];
    $c_challenge=$_POST['How user dealt with challenge or conflict'];
    $c_professional=$_POST['User Professional achievement:'];
    $c_details=$_POST['Details About the user'];

    $file_name=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $temp_name=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];

    //get the extension of the file 
    $base = basename($file_name);
    $extension=substr($base, strlen($base)-4,strlen($base));
    $allowed_extensions=array(".doc","docx",".pdf",".zip",".png");

    if(in_array($extension,$allowed_extensions)){

        $from = $_POST['Email:'];
        $to = "singhiabhin26@gmail.com";
        $subject = "testing";

        $message = "<table width='800' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='8' bordercolor='#CCCCC'>      
        <tr>        
              <td colspan='2' bgcolor='#CDD9F5'><strong>Candidate Details</strong></td>               
        </tr> 
        <tr>        
            <td width='168' bgcolor='#FFFFEC'><strong>Candidate Name</strong></td>        
            <td width='290' bgcolor='#FFFFEC'>$c_name</td>      
        </tr>      
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>E-mail ID</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>$c_email</td>      
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>Time required by user to Join the Company</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>$c_time</td>     
        </tr>                        
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>Linkedin ID</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>$c_linkedin</td>     
        </tr>                        
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>Excel</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>$c_Excel</td>
        </tr>                        
            <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>challenge</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>$c_challenege</td>     
        </tr>                      
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>professional</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>$c_professional</td>  
        </tr>                        
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>details</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>$c_details</td>     
        </tr>                        
     </table>";

        $file=$temp_name;
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
        $uid=md5(uniqid(time()));

        $header= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
        $header.= "reply to:" .$replyto."\r\n";
        $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
        $header .="this is multipart mesage in MIME format.\r\n";
        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

        $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";

        $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

        if(mail($to, $subject, "", $header)){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo"fail";
        }

    }else{
        echo "file type not allowed";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class along with this function

```
    function send_mail_with_attachment($upload_path,$from_name,$from_mail,$replyto,$to,$message,$filenames,$subject) {


$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->setFrom($from_mail, $from_name);
$mail->addAddress($to);     // Add a recipient

$mail->addBCC('test@test.net');
 $mail->addBCC('test@test.com');
$mail->addAttachment($upload_path.$filenames);         // Add attachments
   // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->send()) {

    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'success';
}




    }
```

just download the phpmailer class and `require_once('includes/php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php');` include it in your code . i hope it will work for you

Comment: check your smtp configuration first

Comment: @Abhinav firt try to send simple plain email thrugh php code and test your email sending server i.e smtp server is configure correctly or not

Comment: where i can configure my smtp ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to send email using php. I would recommend you try using phpMailer. You can get it [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). phpMailer is quite good and handles attachments very well

Comment: Are you using gmail? gmail has security measures that restrict data from outside. You should change the setting in your gmail account to accept data from outside

Comment: what changes i have to change in gmail.Any hint on that?

Comment: Change the setting on less secure apps. Hope this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) will help you change

Answer (score 0):

try this its working fine..!

```
<div class="element">
   <a href="http://tenmiles.com/index.php"><img src="logo.gif"></a>
       <br><br>
<div class="new"></div>
<center><h2>Submit Your Information  below</h2></center>

<form  action="1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off"> 
    <!-- <span class="erorr"> --->
    <div class="image"></div>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input id="box1" placeholder="Type here" type="text" name="Name" required>
    <br><br>

<label>Email:</label><input id="box2" placeholder="Type here" type="email" name="Email" required >
    <br>
    <br>

<label>Time period in which you will join</label>
        <select id ="myList" name="Time" >
            <option value="Immediate" required>Immediate</option>
            <option value="Less than one month">Less than one month</option>
            <option value="1 month">1 month</option>
            <option value="2 months">2 months</option> 
        </select>

    <br><br>

<label>Linkedin Link:</label>
    <input type="text" id="box3" name="Linkedin_ID" placeholder="https://www" required >
     <br><br>

    <label for="workexcel">What job responsibilities and duties do you excel at?</label>

    <textarea name="excel" placeholder="Type Here.." id="add" rows="2" cols="2"  maxlength="300" required></textarea>

    <br><br>  

    <label>Tell me about a challenge or conflict you've faced at work, and how you dealt with it.</label>

        <textarea name="conflict" placeholder="Type Here.." rows="2" cols="2" maxlength="300"  required ></textarea>        
    <br><br>


        <label for"twork">What is your greatest professional achievement?</label>

            <textarea name="Professional" placeholder="Type here.." id="twork" rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="300" required></textarea>
            <br>

                <br><br>

    <label for="det">Tell us something about Yourself</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <textarea name= "About" placeholder="Type here.." id="det" rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="300" required ></textarea>

        <br><br>

    <label for="resume">Attach Your Resume here </label>

    <input type="file" name="smtpimg">
    <br><br>


    <input type="checkbox"  value="Area" required>&nbsp;&nbsp;I understand that I am applying for the job which is of my Area of field.
    <br>
    <h1><input id="submit" type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></h1>


    <!-- </span> -->
</form>     


</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

**your php here with smtp code**

```
<?php
include "PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php"; 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
               // $email = $_POST["emailfrom"];
               $target_dir = "smtpimg/";
$target_file= $target_dir .time().basename($_FILES['smtpimg']['name']);
$movefile=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['smtpimg']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
$message = "<table width='800' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='8' bordercolor='#CCCCC'>      
        <tr>        
              <td colspan='2' bgcolor='#CDD9F5'><strong>Candidate Details</strong></td>               
        </tr> 
        <tr>        
            <td width='168' bgcolor='#FFFFEC'><strong>Candidate Name</strong></td>        
            <td width='290' bgcolor='#FFFFEC'>'".$_POST['Name']."'</td>      
        </tr>      
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>E-mail ID</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>'".$_POST['Name']."'</td>      
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>Time required by user to Join the Company</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>'".$_POST['Email']."'</td>     
        </tr>                        
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>Linkedin ID</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>'".$_POST['Linkedin_ID']."'</td>     
        </tr>                        
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>Excel</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>'".$_POST['excel']."'</td>
        </tr>                        
            <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>challenge</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>'".$_POST['conflict']."'</td>     
        </tr>                      
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>professional</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>'".$_POST['Professional']."'</td>  
        </tr>                        
        <tr>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'><strong>details</strong></td>        
            <td bgcolor='#FFFFDD'>'".$_POST['About']."'</td>     
        </tr>                        
     </table>";
     print_r($message);
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 

$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "yourusername@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourgmailpassword";
$mail->AddReplyTo("reply@yourdomain.com", "Reply name");
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['Email'],'ashu');
$mail->Subject = "SMTP Receivced";
$mail->Body = "<b>Succesfully SMTP Receivced</b>";
$mail->AddAttachment($target_file);
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
$file = 'index.php';
$crlf = "\n";
$hdrs = array(
              'From'    => 'you@yourdomain.com',
              'Subject' => 'Test mime message'
              );
if($mail->send($hdrs))
 {
echo "<script> alert('Successfully Mailed');window.location = 'pra-2.php';</script>";
}
else{
echo "Mailed Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: HEY i am getting the file in my mail now but only the attachment is missing i have used this code for attachment             



`$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);`

Comment: please check the above piece of code of mine and let me know

Comment: create the folder for an image..and check it..! I've done perfectly above code ..just verify clearly #abhinav